# Creating a Managed Package issues

Tags: managed-package

I'm working on creating a managed package and having some issues.

I created a fresh Partner Dev org, set the namespace, pushed the metadata from SFDX to the org, ready to create the package.

Go to Setup > Package Manager > New (package). I type in the name, select managed, and proceed to the screen where you add all the items into your package.

I add the main app, then need to add Classes (test classes) so I select those and Add. This is where I run into a problem... I accidentally included the Forgot Password class that is in the Dev org by default -- not one of my classes. So I want to remove it... but how? It's in the list of included components, along with a visualforce page I don't want, and there's no way to delete it from the list.

So I figure I'll delete the package and start over. No can do. Even though I don't have a package (I deleted it), I get an error saying the org can only have one package.

Do I really have to go create a whole new dev org, push my metadata again, etc? I can't believe there's no room for undoing a minor oversight. Am I missing something? I'm still practicing, so I haven't burned my release namespace, but I'm paranoid that I might accidentally make a similar mistake when I get around to the gold release.

Comment: If you can’t delete it the something in the package is referencing it. Remove that first and the. Then delete link will appear. Assuming you have not released the version yet. If you have you need to submit a case to enable deletion of managed package components and must be a partner.

Comment: @Eric Thanks, that makes sense. I appreciate the tip.